# imread fails to read image

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, imread

I have been working on a project to detect offline hand written signatures. And I have run into a basic problem. My program fails to work with `imread()` function. It does not show any errors, but it does not load an image either. If I check for the image, it displays the error message I specified. I am using OpenCV 2.4.10 with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and I am using Windows 8.

Is this the problem with the way I configured OpenCV or is it something wrong with the version?

How do I overcome with this problem?

If you have any perfect tutorial to configure OpenCV with Microsoft Visual C++, Please share it with me. Here is the code I am running. And also, while running, The output dialogue box says, *Native' has exited with code -1*. Now I don't see message, "*Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!*". But still the problem is not solved.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Shareit\Photo\New Doc 7_1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    if (image.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
      cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
      //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
      return -1;
 }

      namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
      imshow("MyWindow", image); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

      waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

      destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's either foggy outside or my crystal ball isn't happy, so I can't see your code from here.  Please add a small example of code, TO YOUR QUESTION, (not a screen snapshot), which demonstrates the issue.  I have no idea if your parameters to `imread` are correct or not.

Comment: You may consider posting a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: in a string you have to use `/` or `\\ ` because a single backslash is for things like `\n`

Comment: `"C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Shareit\Photo\New Doc 7_1.jpg"` Remember you need to escape `\\` in string literals or just use / instead.

Comment: Thanks drescherjm :) I got it now, and its working fine.

Comment: Try by giving path like this: **C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\Shareit\\Photo\\New Doc 7_1.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

I've been working myself with opencv lately and this is the best opencv tutorial for Visual Studio that I've found so far:

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html

Mainly, what you need to do configure it correctly is the following:

**Set up Enviromental Variable** in: My computer->Propierties->Advanced System Settings-> Enviromental variables-> 
Create a new one with these parameters: Variable name: OPENCV_DIR, Variable value: C:\opencv\build\

Edit the variable "Path", to do so, add at the end of the line of "variable name" the following: ;%OPENCV_DIR%\x86\vc11\bin

**Then you should configure Visual Studio:**

Right click on the project name and then click "Propierties"
In C/C++->General-> Additional Include Directories, copy and paste "$(OPENCV_DIR)\include"

In Linker->General->Additional Library Directories copy and paste $(OPENCV_DIR)\x86\vc11\lib

In Linker->Input->Additional dependencies, click Edit and add the libraries that you found in "'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib"

Note: If your system is 64 bits instead of 32 bits, replace "x86" with "x64"

Can you post your code to analyze the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Alisse, But even I followed the same tutorial, and still there's some problem. There is no problem with the functions that use IplImage*. If it was a linker error, all other programs would have also not worked. So I am not able to figure out where exactly is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) provides a tutorial to setup OpenCV with Visual Studio, and there is also some sample code which uses cv::imread to load an image included at the bottom.